# Create SVG object with name spaces

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to create an svg image and text object both of these objects need namespaces to set the xlink:href and xml:space property.  I've tried the following code with no luck to create these objects so I can add them to the screen:

```
function createSVGNode(node) {
    var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'svg');
    var ns2 = null;
    if(node.nodeName == 'image') { ns2 = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'; }
    var shape = document.createElementNS(ns2, node.nodeName);
    svg.appendChild(shape);
    var ns = null;
    for(var attr = 0; attr < node.attributes.length; attr++) {
        if(node.nodeName == 'image' && node.attributes[attr].nodeName == 'xlink:href') {
            ns = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';
        }
        if(node.nodeName == 'text' && node.attributes[attr].nodeName == 'xml:space') {
            ns = 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace';
        }
        shape.setAttributeNS(ns, node.attributes[attr].nodeName, node.attributes[attr].nodeValue);
        ns = null;
    }
    if(node.childNodes.length == 1) shape.appendChild(node.childNodes[0]);
    return shape;
}
```

I'm sure I'm going about this much harder than I need to but everything was working until I had to deal with the image and text objects.

Answer (score 0):

SVG elements are in the SVG namespace

```
var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
var shape = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', node.nodeName);
svg.appendChild(shape);
var ns = null;
for(var attr = 0; attr < node.attributes.length; attr++) {
    if(node.nodeName == 'image' && node.attributes[attr].nodeName == 'xlink:href') {
        ns = 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink';
    }
    if(node.nodeName == 'text' && node.attributes[attr].nodeName == 'xml:space') {
        ns = 'http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace';
    }
    shape.setAttributeNS(ns, node.attributes[attr].nodeName, node.attributes[attr].nodeValue);
    ns = null;
}
if(node.childNodes.length == 1) shape.appendChild(node.childNodes[0]);
return shape;
```

Comment: not working for either the image object or the text object, what I've done is viewed the dynamic markup to see what namespaces were given to the elements by default and those namespaces are in my example.

Comment: lets say I add an attribute with the http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink name space, and like in my example I added the image object with the http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink name space is the DOM smart enough to create the image object as <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ... />